# Pairs of $2\times 2$ matrices generating free groups.

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, free-groups, linear-groups

The matrices $\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\2&1\end{pmatrix}$ are well-known to (freely) generate a free group.  Some years ago, I read a paper that, if memory serves, sort of summarised what was known about generalisations to pairs of the form $\begin{pmatrix}1&\lambda\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\\lambda&1\end{pmatrix}$.  (Or perhaps even more general such pairs.) I recall that there were results there describing regions in $\mathbb{C}$ from which $\lambda$ chould be chosen so that such a pair freely generated a free group, and there were plots of these regions (at least one, anyway).  Unfortunately, I cannot recall the title or author(s) of the paper, and Googling didn't turn up anything that looked familiar.

> Does anyone recall such a paper and be able to provide a reference.

(I did find a 1967 paper by Lyndon and Ullman, but that wasn't it, and I think the one I'm after was later, and probably described further progress on the question, probably with its own new results.)

Answer (score 6):

There's a ***1969*** paper by Lyndon and Ullman that appears to be it, plots and all.

> R. C. Lyndon and J. L. Ullman, *Groups generated by two parabolic linear fractional transformations.* Canad. J. Math. **21** (1969) 1388-1403

The [article](http://cms.math.ca/cjm/v21/cjm1969v21.1388-1403.pdf) itself is available online, but I'm not sure whether it's free, or I'm seeing it because of my University's subscription. (Most likely the former applies.)

Comment: The PDF seems to be freely available.

Answer (score 3):

For a slightly more recent reference see

M. Yu. Lyubich, V. V. Suvorov, Free subgroups of $SL_2(C)$ with two parabolic generators
Journal of Soviet Mathematics, 1988, Volume 41, Issue 2, p. 976-979.

Answer (score 1):

FREE AND NONFREE SUBGROUPS OF $PSL_2(\mathbf{C})$ GENERATED BY TWO PARABOLIC ELEMENTS
by Ju A Ignatov

1979 Math. USSR Sb. 35 49. doi:10.1070/SM1979v035n01ABEH001449